# How to setup jenkins in ubuntu 12.04 manually?

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins-plugins, firewall

I have a machine in production which is running Ubuntu 12.04. I need to setup Jenkins on it. I was trying to follow this tutorial -

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-jenkins-on-ubuntu-12-04

But I am not able to make it work since the first line which I am trying to execute it's not working at all -

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

This line just hangs and it doesn't do anything. It makes me think that there is a firewall and we cannot access any outside link.

This is what I got when I ran wget -

```
david@machineA:~$ wget https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
--2015-03-30 13:21:20--  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Resolving jenkins-ci.org... 199.193.196.24
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:21:44--  (try: 2)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:22:07--  (try: 3)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:22:31--  (try: 4)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443...
```

So now is there any other way by which I can setup jenkins in my production machine cleanly?

Any step by step guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you normally install stuff on your production boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are not connected to the Internet, you can either fix your internet connection or manually download the jenkins .deb files and copy them to your production machine.

Comment: I am not much into linux so if you can provide me step by step, then it will be of great help. Where I can download `.deb` files and where I should put it? Appreciated your help.

Comment: get the latest one from here http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ copy it to your server and do ```dpkg -i filename.deb```

Comment: I can copy it to my home directory right? And after executing the second command, what it will do? Does it gett started automatically in the same way it is mentioned in the tutorial?

Comment: I suggest you to _read_ the tutorial you linked.```Jenkins will be launched as a daemon up on start. See /etc/init.d/jenkins for more details.```